# Show that $x^{\frac1x}<1.5$ for $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: inequality, induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Well, I've proven that :
$$x^{\frac1x}<1.5$$ for $x \in \mathbb R^+$, or more specifically I've shown that the maximum value of the expression is $1.44...$ for $x = e$. But I used calculus (finding the derivative, then finding the critical point and proving it is a local max).

But I'm looking for another method that does not require calculus (induction if possible, that's why I added $x \in \mathbb N$). The induction step seems pretty hard: I have no way to simplify $(x+1)^{\frac1{x+1}}$. Any help would be appreciated. (AM-GM inequality seems a good idea, though I am not able to proceed further..., or more specifically, it's not working for smaller values of x.)

Comment: well it does answer, now that @MichaelRozenberg suggested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in\{1,2,3\}$ it's obvious.

For $x\in\mathbb N$ and $x\geq3$ it's enough to prove that $$x^{\frac{1}{x}}>(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}}$$ or
$$x^{x+1}>(x+1)^x,$$  for which we can use induction. See here: [Prove by induction that $(k + 2)^{k + 1} \leq (k+1)^{k +2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633720/)

Comment: how is the link related to $x^{1\over x} > (x+1)^{1\over x+1}$

Comment: @D S I added something. See now.

Comment: thank you! But is there no way that avoids manual verification of ${1,2,3}$?

Comment: @D S No. Because if $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ so $f$ increases on $(0,e]$ and decreases on $[e,+\infty)$.